# Порядок выполнения функции вместе с вызовом sleep()

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы функция выполнялась там, где я её написал, а не когда я обращаюсь к скрипту? Функция выполняется первой, потом остальное, например:

```
<?
echo 'grg';
sleep(10);
?>
```

В данном случае выполняется задержка, а потом выводится "grg". А мне надо, чтобы всё было по порядку.

Answer (score 3):

У Вас это происходит из-за того что результат работы скрипта отправляется на клиента после его завершения в общем случае.

Можно наверное воспользоваться функцией [flush](http://hr.php.net/manual/ru/function.flush.php):

```
<? 
echo 'grg'; flush();sleep(10);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Они и выполняются последовательно, просто вывод буферизируется. Можно попробовать так (хотя какой в этом смысл не очень понятно):

```
echo 'grg';
flush();
sleep(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Результат вывода записывается в буфер и пользователю отправляется либо по завершению скрипта либо по достижению максимального размера буфера, установленного в конфигах.

Попробуйте делать так

```
<? 
echo 'grg'; flush();
sleep(10);

?>
```